# Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11FontManager using openjdk 8 on alpine linux

Tags: docker, fonts, java, alpine-linux

I'm getting this stack trace when using openjdk 8 with this docker image: openjdk:8-jre-alpine

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11FontManager

at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:82) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
at java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:491) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
at java.awt.Font.getFontName(Font.java:1279) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
at java.awt.Font.getFontName(Font.java:1261) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
```

It works fine using the Oracle version

Following some directions to install the dejavu fonts from here: https://hub.docker.com/r/neduekwunife/openjdk8-jre-alpine-with-fontconfig/
I added the following line to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add --update ttf-dejavu && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

which now gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so: Error relocating /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so: AWTFontDefaultChar: symbol not found
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this to work by reverting to an older version of openjdk container.  Here is the FROM statement in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8u121-jre-alpine
```

which replaced this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
```

which is currently equivalent to update 131.

There is a bug for this documented here:  https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/7372

Comment: you saved my day Jason, thanks! looks like this issue still not fixed on Alpine side..

Comment: The bug for this has been fixed and using the latest image works now.